# Nativescript Sentry not getting user data when the App crashes

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, sentry

I've successfully tracked errors that are appearing on our app. I'm setting the user data when the user logins so when the the errorHandler fires we are sending the user data as well.

The issue I'm running into is when the app fails outside the error handler.

On our sentry.io is receiving two different sets of data for when a user causes and error and and the app actually crashes. It seems like it users sentry-java when the app crashes, and uses raven-js when the user causes an error.

[image]

[image]

My question is:
Is it possible to set up userdata for the sentry-java issues? And why is it indicating different SDK's in the sentry error log.

Comment: You are trying to pass some object from Nativescript into Java so it can be part of the sentry log?